# React + Typescript - Refs typing errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

I have seen many other questions with the same problem as mine, and I have tried all solutions, but it is not working. I have a form with many inputs, which I have customized in `FloatingLabelInputs`. They have a public method called `resetState`, that I want to call. Here is what my component with the form looks like:

```ts
class EditModalPage extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  fieldsRefs: React.RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>[] = fields.map(() => React.createRef());

  render() {
    return fields.map((fieldData, index) => (
      <FloatingLabelInput
        name={fieldData.name}
        ref={this.fieldRefs[index]}
      />
    ));
  }
}

const fields = [
  { name: 'test' }
];
```

From what I've seen in other questions, this should work, as I have typed the `fieldsRefs` property using `React.RefObject`. However it doesn't, and the error TypeScript gives me is the following:

```
Type 'RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>' is not assignable to type 'string | (string & ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void)) | (string & RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) | (RefObject<FloatingLabelInput> & string) | (RefObject<FloatingLabelInput> & ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void)) | ... 5 more ... | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>' is not assignable to type '((instance: FloatingLabelInput | null) => void) & RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Type 'RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>' is not assignable to type '(instance: FloatingLabelInput | null) => void'.
      Type 'RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>' provides no match for the signature '(instance: FloatingLabelInput | null): void'.
```

If I try to `console.log(this.fieldsRefs)`, everything is working, though. I just get the error and am forced to cast `as any`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the props interface for the `<FloatingLabelInput />` component : it seems like it requires a ref of type `RefObject<HtmlInputElement>` and you are trying to give it a `RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>`.

You should try changing the type from `React.RefObject<FloatingLabelInput>` to `React.RefObject<HtmlInputElement>`

Comment: Actually, no. I want to get the ref for the FloatingLabelInput, as it has a public method that I need to access. Also, I've been having the same issue with other components...

Answer (score 0):

Try this type: `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>`